Optimizing Matrix Equation to solve it faster
I have written code to extract the symbolic inverse of a matrix to obtain the inverse of this 18*18 matrix. I am running to on google colab. It has taken 2 hours and has not yet been solved. Is there any other way to obtain the inverse of the same in a faster manner either mathematically or via code to optimize the process? I am finding the inverse as I need to solve for x where ax=b, hence a inverse is what I am looking for. If there are any suggestions let me know.
`import sympy as sp

# Define symbolic variables
x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6, x_7, x_8, x_9, x_10, x_11, x_12, x_13, x_14 = sp.symbols('x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 x_5 x_6 x_7 x_8 x_9 x_10 x_11 x_12 x_13 x_14')

# Define the symbolic matrix
matrix = sp.Matrix([
    [1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 2, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 2, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6, x_7, x_8, x_9, x_10, x_11, x_12, x_13, x_14, -1],
    [0, 0, 0, x_1, x_2, x_3, 0, 0, 0, 0, x_8, x_9, x_10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, x_1, (2*x_2), (2*x_3), 0, 0, x_6, (2*x_7), x_8, x_9, (2*x_10), (2*x_11), x_12, (2*x_13), x_14, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, x_3, x_4, (2*x_5), (2*x_6), 2 * x_7, 2 * x_8, x_9, 2 * x_10, x_11, 0, 0, x_14, 0]
])

# Calculate the inverse of the matrix symbolically
matrix_inv = matrix.inv()

# Print the inverted matrix
print(matrix_inv)`

I have written code to extract the symbolic inverse of a matrix to obtain the inverse of this 18*18 matrix. I am running to on google colab.

How comes you know part of the matrix and not the other? Is there a particular formation of the unknown part?

You might want to consider swapping the solver matrix_inv = matrix.inv(method="LU") which would replace the default Gaussian elimination with LU decomposition (if applicable to your case)

No the other matrix I do know, it is not included here yet.

It probably isn't a good idea to generate the symbolic inverse of such a large matrix. What do you hope to learn by doing it? Solving the thing numerically by Gaussian elimination ought to be OK for such a modestly sized matrix unless it is very nearly singular. If it is then you might want to try doing it in extended precision or by SVD.

This related post might be helpful. It explains, why the calculation is probably not feasible as you have noticed already.
